# How to retrieve image url form firebase database andriod

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

I am working on a android project where I use firebase as my backend. I have stored a image in the database as url, and am trying the fetch the image in the app using [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/). But I am not able to retrieve the image form database. Below is my code.

Fragment class which I am using to get the data:

```
public class McaFirstSemSylabus extends Fragment {

    public ImageView mcafirstsemsylbausimag;

    Syllabus sl;
    DatabaseReference loadmcafirstsylabus;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mca_first_sem_sylabus, container, false);
        loadmcafirstsylabus = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Syllabus").child("McaSyllabus").child("Firstsem");

        mcafirstsemsylbausimag = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mcasylabus_img);

         String img = sl.getImg();

        Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(img).into(mcafirstsemsylbausimag);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Below is the POJO class which consist of getters and setters:

```
public class Syllabus {

    private String img;

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public Syllabus(){
    }

    public Syllabus(String image) {
        this.img = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue here? NullPointerException at `sl.getImg();`?

Comment: yes thats my erorr "Null pointerException"

Comment: And do you understand what that means? How to fix it? Please [edit] with the logcat.

Comment: `sl.getImg()` is **not** getting a url from Firebase, so I'm not sure why you think you need `sl` variable

Answer (score 1):

That's because your Syllabus object is empty ! 
You have to give a ValueEventListener to the object you have stored in that specific child

```
 loadmcafirstsylabus.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //this retrives the java object you saved in that particular child
                sl = dataSnapshot.getValue(Syllabus.class);
                String img = sl.getImg();

                //rest of your code
                }
```

Comment: I tried the above code modification still i am getting null pointer exception error.

Comment: sory for the above comment. i cleaned my project and run again the code is working properly thank you so much..

Comment: Cool ! notice that i've used addListenerForSingleValueEvent so that the above code only runs once, depending on your needs you might want to use addValueEventListener so be careful